# Merge matrix in for loop matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

i have a matrix `c[38,39]`, and want to merge it to a new one lets say `f[1,1482]`. So first i pre-allocate the `f` and then in a for loop i tried to merge it, but it keeps saying that i exceeded the matrix dimensions.I know that there is the `cat` function but i get the same results, maybe the `reshape` function will help? Any advice appretiated, thanks in advance.

```
f=[];       %// pre-allocating the mew matrix
for k=1:1482    %// 1482=38*39
f(:,k)=[c(:,1);c(:,k)]; %// merging 
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It exceeds matrix dimensions because the second dimension of c is 39 and your loop is referencing values up to 1482.

Reshape may help if you are looking at different matrix sizes but if you are just wanting to convert from a matrix to a vector then just using the (:) notation works.

```
c=rand(38,39);
f=c(:)';
```

ps. pre-allocating f only really helps if you specify the final matrix size. Here all you have done is declared an empty matrix which then expands on each loop iteration.